# middle button problem of 3 button mouse(not wheel mouse)?

Tags: mouse

I installed Ubuntu 22.4 version. Also, I am using a 3-button mouse, not a wheel button mouse. I installed Ubuntu to use Houdini for Linux. However, the middle mouse button does not work properly in Houdini.
However, in web browsers, the middle button of a three-button mouse works like a wheel mouse button.

When I went to the Houdini forum, they said that the mouse settings were incorrect in Ubuntu.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

What is the funciton of the middle button in Houdini? And what does it do in your browser?

I would run `xev` in a terminal which will open a small window. Moving over the window and clicking on the window (keep mouse still) will show you what the buttons are doing. The buttons might report as "button 1/2/3 etc" for mouse buttons or they could be  mapped to keypresses. Or could be not registering at all, it depends on your config.

Depending on your results you may be able to use `xbindkeys` to re-map the middle button.